# Do I need to apply Visa to UK with Italian spouse?

Tags: uk, indonesian-citizens

I'm Indonesian passport holder with Italian husband, I have Carta di soggiorno per familiari di cittadino dell'Unione. Can I go to London without Visa?

Comment: You can check [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y). The only way you could travel to the UK without a visa is by applying for a free family permit if your partner or family member is from the EU, Switzerland, Norway, Iceland or Liechtenstein **and** they have been living in the UK before 1 January 2021.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you can't. Whether you need a visa for the UK is decided by your citizenship. Being an Indonesian citizen, you need a visa for the UK. Even if you were married to a British citizen, you would still require a visa to visit the UK.

Incidentally, when UK was a part of the EU, technically, you could have been allowed entry into the UK without a visa if you were traveling with your husband, as a family member of an EU citizen traveling with them and having a residence card as an EU national family member. But not now.

Comment: The only exception to this is [EUSS family permits](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit), but for that your EU citizen partner needs to have been living in the UK before brexit. Not relevant in the case of OP, but might be useful to someone else with the same question.

Comment: + unless you have firsthand experience, I doubt that airlines would reject boarding. [Timatic clearly indicates that EU citizens' partners are exempted from visa requirements](https://imgur.com/a/R3LQek0) on relevant EU but not-schengen countries (Ireland, Cyprus, Bulgaria etc).

Comment: Yes, I missed that her residence permit from Italy is an EU family permit. I was guessing a normal Italian residence permit because her husband is Italian citizen. EU family permit is usually issued in a third EU country. But also possible in the country of citizenship after relocation from another EU country after getting an EU family permit from that country. I missed the "familiari di cittadino dell'Unione" part. So going to Ireland is possible, (and UK too in the past).

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: "EU family permit" was the term for the UK's visa issued to family members of union citizens, analogous to the EUSS family permit it continues to issue.  The residence document in this case is a "residence card of a family member of a union citizens" or "article 10 card" (or also "article 20 card," though the directive is a bit ambiguous on that point).

Comment: I just used it in an informal way rather than a proper term.

Comment: I figured.  But that has caused confusion in the past.  That's probably less likely now that (formal) family permits are approaching obsolescence, but I still think it's better to be precise.  (And I have to say that I find the EU distinction between "permit" and "card" to be a bit over the top, but even so it makes an important point.)

Comment: I have edited the answer and changed it to "residence card as an EU national family member" which is given on the EU webpage regarding travel of family members of the EU citizens to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused. So, if I have Carta di Soggiorno di Familiare Di Un Cittadino dell'Unione (Residence Card of the family member of a European Union citizen) and I travel with my Italian husband, I can travel to UK without Visa? Or I can't? Thanks

Comment: @Alice because the UK left the European Union, there is no longer a visa exemption for travelers who have a _Carta di Soggiorno di Familiare Di Un Cittadino dell'Unione_ (Residence Card of the family member of a European Union citizen).  Therefore, if you need a visa to visit the UK by yourself, you also need a visa to visit the UK with your husband.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I really appreciate it. 